# Oracle "sdo_net_mem.network_manager.shortest_path" code not working

Tags: oracle, shortest-path, oracle-spatial

I tried to create a spatial network in oracle Sql developer Client Editor;
When I tried to this code, its gave me "True" result;

```
SELECT SDO_NET.NETWORK_EXISTS('network_name') FROM DUAL;
```

it means SDO_NET commands are working properly.

But, When I tried to this code;

```
DECLARE
  cost NUMBER;
  path_id NUMBER;
  res_numeric NUMBER;
BEGIN
   path_id := sdo_net_mem.network_manager.shortest_path('network_name',source_node_id, dest_node_id);
   cost := SDO_NET_MEM.PATH.GET_COST('network_name', path_id);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The ID of the shortest path from X to Y is: ' || path_id || ' and it costs ' || cost);
END;
```

Gave me that result;

[image]

How I can solve this; Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you load the network first ? You do that using the SDO_NET_MEM.NETWORK_MANAGER.READ_NETWORK() procedure. In your case:

```
SDO_NET_MEM.NETWORK_MANAGER.READ_NETWORK('network_name', 'TRUE');
```

Note that the SDO_NET_MEM package has been deprecated in 12c and should no longer be used.

Comment: is there any another possible way to create spatial network in oracle ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this procedure to check your network

`select SDO_NET.VALIDATE_NETWORK('network_name') from dual;`

what is your oracle version?

Normally we execute the read network before running any network methods.